# Edit default errors in Django-passwords

Tags: python, django

I am using Django-passwords package for password strength.
But I want to change its default errors like

```
Invalid Length (Must be 8 characters or more)
Based on a common sequence of characters
Must be more complex (Must contain 1 or more uppercase characters)
etc...
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source of the package in question](https://github.com/dstufft/django-passwords/blob/master/passwords/validators.py), it unfortunately doesn't seem like it's very easy to change the message strings without practically copy-pasting all the validator code to change the messages.